# Android sqlite сбои при работе с cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

В статистике приходит большое количество сбоев, связанных с sqlite. Например, при такой операции:

```
String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
//x = cursor.getCount();
}
```

По информации из статистики, какой-то закономерности в версии android не прослеживается. Сам поймать момент тоже не могу - на нескольких различных устройствах тестил, ничего не падает.

Стек из статистики:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException:
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2946)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3081)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1831)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:201)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6810)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:873)


Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement (Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement (SQLiteConnection.java:903)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare (SQLiteConnection.java:514)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare (SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init> (SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init> (SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query (SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory (SQLiteDatabase.java:1408)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery (SQLiteDatabase.java:1347)
at Вызов метода в mainActivity
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7224)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7213)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1272)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2926)
```

Может найдутся знающие

Comment: А стек ошибки где? Это просто стек вызова! Из этого куска кода могу с ходу предположить: 1) Не найдена таблица в БД 2) На момент записи в БД, чтение блокируется.

Comment: Это все, что мне выдает статистика. SQLiteException, мой метод, в котором вылетело исключение и вот этот стек